# How to repeat rows based on different columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, weekday

I have table with columns `Monday`, `Tuesday`, `Wednesday`, `Thursday` and `Friday` and are of *Boolean type* now I want to make a query to convert these rows to single column `Weekday`. It Should show me *name of day* of which column is true.

Comment: SQL Server does not have a `Boolean` type.

Comment: BTW, SQL server has a Bit Data type that is a Boolean type.

Answer (score 2):

> Note: I think you mean `bit` type instead of `Boolean` that accepts only `0`/`1`.

A mathematical way can be this:

```
select 
    datename(weekday,
       Monday + Tuesday*2 + Wednesday*3 + Thursday*4 + Friday*5 - 1) as weekDayName
from 
    t;
```

[**[ SQL Fiddle Demo ]**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/5161)

> Side Note:
>
> ```
> datename(weekday, 0) => Monday
> datename(weekday, 1) => Tuesday
> datename(weekday, 2) => Wednesday
> datename(weekday, 3) => Thursday
> datename(weekday, 4) => Friday
> datename(weekday, 5) => Saturday
> datename(weekday, 6) => Sunday / datename(weekday, -1) => Sunday
> ```

Comment: thanks a lot for your time and concern I have used also another way....

Comment: Well done.  Should have been the Accepted Answer  +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case`.  To get a comma-delimited list in SQL Server:

```
select t.*,
       stuff( ((case when Monday <> 0 then ',Monday' else '' end) +
               (case when Tuesday <> 0 then ',Tuesday' else '' end) +
               . . .
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as weekdays
from t;
```

I don't know how you specify "true" values.  The above assumes that non-zero values are true.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, SQL Server does not have a boolean type, but it does have a `BIT` type which can only take on two values, 0 and 1.  I am assuming that you are using a bit column.  I also assume that only one day will be selected in each row.  With both of these assumptions, you just need a single `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Monday = 1    THEN 'Monday'
         WHEN Tuesday = 1   THEN 'Tuesday'
         WHEN Wednesday = 1 THEN 'Wednesday'
         WHEN Thursday = 1  THEN 'Thursday'
         WHEN Friday = 1    THEN 'Friday' END AS day_selected
FROM yourTable
```